# Samsung Tizen Web Application: How to install on TV?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I am right now developing a Web App for Samsung Tizen TVs.
My setup is as follows:

Samsung Tizen Studio 4.5.1

Samsung Tizen Smart TV GQ75Q95TGTXZG

The TV can be connected to the PC via the Samsung Device Manager just fine as long as the Developer Mode is enabled on the TV. I can then run my app directly on the TV by running it from within Tizen Studio. However I'd like to get the app on my TV more permanently.
In the Device Manager I have clicked the "Install App" menu entry in the context menu of my TV. Then, nothing happens. No error message, but also I cannot find the app on the TV.

I have also tried loading the Tizen widget onto a USB drive and inserting that drive into the TV but the app is not recognized. I tried it two different ways: Once I placed all files in the root directory of the drive and once I placed them into a "userwidget" sub directory. Both times the drive is recognized, but the app on it is not.

I have also created a cetificate in the Samsung Certificate Manager and the Device Manager is recognizing it correctly (as far as I can tell).

Is there any way to analyze what's causing the app to not appear on the screen?
I am running out of ideas.
Intensive searching on the web has also not yielded any useful results past what I have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

What can I suggest you to get more details of a problem is to use a [Tizen CLI](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/running-and-testing-your-app/sdb?langredirect=1) instead of Tizen Studio. It could possibly give you better look on the problem of installation.

I guess that commands below can be useful to you:

- sdb devices - to show the list of connected devices
- sdb connect  - to connect to your device via network
- sdb shell - to enter device shell
- sdb install <wgt_file_on_local_PC> - to install your wgt package on the device
- sdb dlog - to check logs during installation process - maybe there will be something useful

Regarding of what could be a problem, I've found [this tutorial](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/get-started/tv/first-samsung-tv-app/#run-on-a-target-device) which mentions the point:

> 4. Right-click the device and select Permit to install application.

According to your desription of a problem, it could be somehow related.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can know, there are 2 methods to install app on real Samsung TV device (for testing purpose):

1. Via **USB Demo Packaging Tool** on Samsung Seller Portal page (https://seller.samsungapps.com/tv/login). But you need to register for Partnership account (you can also submit application to Samsung App store later as well), to be able to use this tool.
2. Via wifi network (debugable):

- Make sure your TV and the laptop/PC are connected with the same network.
- Get the DUID code of TV (in Settings -> About this TV).
- Create a certificate profile ( as you mentioned before), enter the DUID in the required step.
- Enable **Developer Mode** on TV: Go to APPS -> enter "12345" using the remote control or the on-screen number keypad.
- Please refer this official link:

https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-device.html

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see if you did this --- to install on the TV (temporarily) you can use the 'USB Demo Packaging tool' from Samsung

https://seller.samsungapps.com/tv/tool/usb-package

You upload the .wgt file, and it will spit-back a .tps and .license file.  Put those two files in the 'userwidget' folder of your FAT32 formatted usb drive.  It usually pops up a "do you want to browse these files?" and you say 'no' to that.   About 2-5 seconds later, it will go 'installing  will be started'.  Give it a minute, and it should succeed.  If it does not succeed, you may have to make a new .wgt file and start the whole process over again.  Most likely though you're trying to install an application with the same Tizen Widget ID as an application you already have installed --- you may need to delete that off in advance.

When you login to the seller.samsungapps.com store it's on the left under 'tools'.